# Xcode Display Image if there is no image on Imageview

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement, nsuserdefaults

I need help to make something like this

```
IBOutlet UIImageView *imageview;
IBOutlet UIImageView *imageview2;

if(imageview have no image){
 SET this image @"x";
}else if(imageview2 have no image){
 Set this Image @"x";
}
```

And save and load the code with `NSUserDefaults`

Comment: You should consider reading a book or going through some developer guides that Apple has graciously provided. Don't take offense to this. This is all fundamental programming that you should know spending 15-20 min studying the topic at hand. Or if you have tried something please edit your question to include the things you have tried

Comment: What is it what you wat to achieve? What error do you get?:

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
UIImageView *myImageView;
if(myImageView.image){
myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage1"];
  //image exists
}
else {
myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myOtherImage"];
//image doesnt exists
}
//by this time some image or the other will be set so we save the image
[[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults]setObject:myImageView.image forKey:@"myImage"];
```

I dont know if NSUserDefault can set image object coz I havnt tried it u might get an exception, its best if you can save the image's name right in the if statement by using `[[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults] setObject:@"imagenameoftheimage" forKey:@"myImageName]"`

Comment: Thanks but can you help me with the NSUserDefaults so i can save and load aswell pls

Comment: Dont know i dident do it i cant do it i have to have 15 somthink